# Can I configure an MSI to install silently to a non-default directory?

Tags: installation, automation, windows-installer

I have a vendor supplied MSI file, and we want to automate the install to a couple thousand pcs/servers. Unfortunately, we would like to install it to our default apps directory, which is not c:\program files.  Is there a way to do this easily? I'm experimenting with Orca, but I'd rather get a solid method on how to do this quickly and easily.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the target directory on the command line:

```
msiexec /i /qn setup.msi INSTALLDIR=c:\customfolder\program\
```

Comment: Turns out it's INSTALLDIR, but thanks, you got me most of the way there! :)